# NGX-Pagination with dropdown paging

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I m using ngx-pagination and try to convert the paging into drop down (Angular 6)

See for detail:
https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination

```
First  Prev  DDOWN   NEXT   LAST


<select  >          
  <option *ngFor="let page of p.pages" [value]="page.label">{{page.label}}</option> 
</select>
```

I am facing two problems:

- It gives the list of pages like 1 2 3 4 ... 32
- Other on changing page by first. next last ... dropdown value is not changing